# SSRS Future Date

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

Im building a basic SSRS report that is a quote. I have a date field of when data was put into the system. On the quote I want to take that field and add 30 days to it so I can show that the quote is good for the next 30 days out. How would I write that in my expression in SSRS?

What I have so far:

=First(Fields!Date.Value, "DataSet1")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [DateAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337194%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) function.

Example: `DateAdd("d", 30, First(Fields!Date.Value, "DataSet1"))`

Comment: `=DateAdd("d", 30, First(Fields!Date.Value, "DataSet1"))`  it wouldn't let me just add the `=` sign.